# How to check for two colliders changing the color on those three objects but not other instances with the same script attached?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I want to do a specific thing. I have random running letters falling down from the sky. Imagine something like Matrix. But when specific combinantion of numbers appears (909) I want them to turn red.

I have did following and it works partially.

On prefab with the mesh of number 0 I have attached following script

```
public class RedNumberZero : MonoBehaviour
{

 Renderer rend;

 public bool red;

 List <GameObject> currentCollisions = new List <GameObject> ();

 void Start()
  {
      rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
  }

  void OnTriggerEnter (Collider col) {

      if (col.tag == "9")
      {
      // Add the GameObject collided with to the list.
      currentCollisions.Add (col.gameObject);
      }

      if (currentCollisions.Count == 2)
      {
          red = true;
          Color color = rend.material.color;
          rend.material.color = Color.red;
          Debug.Log("collision");
      }


  }
```

On prefab with number 9 mesh i have the following script

```
public class RedNumberNine : MonoBehaviour
 {
     private bool zeroCol;
     Renderer rend;
     private RedNumberZero zeroScript;
     void Awake()
     {
         zeroScript = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<RedNumberZero> ();
     }
     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
     }
     void OnTriggerEnter (Collider col) {
         if (col.tag == "0")
          {
          zeroCol = true;
          Debug.Log("Coll 2");
          }

     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         if(zeroScript.red == true && zeroCol == true)
         {
             ColorChange();

         }
     }

     void ColorChange()
     {
         Color color = rend.material.color;
         rend.material.color = Color.red;
     }
 }
```

It works strange. I cannot describe the behaviour thoroughly / because i dont really understand what exactly happening. But what the biggest problem actually is that if all of those conditionts are passed alll of my instances of prefabs on the scene with the script attached turn red. I want this to happen just and only on a place where combination "909" appears.

Any idea what i could do better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I like how you designed it but to answer the question:

```
zeroScript = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<RedNumberZero>();
```

[`FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html)

> Returns the first active loaded object of Type type.

gets the reference to the **first** found instance of `RedNumberZero` in your scene => It will be the same for all instances of `RedNumberNine` one as long as it isn't destroyed.

---

It should rather be e.g.

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider col) 
{
     if (col.CompareTag("0"))
     {
         // Get the RedNumberZero that actually collides with you
         var zeroScript = col.GetComponent<RedNumberZero>();

         zeroCol = zeroScript && zeroScript.red;
     }
 }
```

---

There is still a problem here: You are assuming that `OnTriggerEnter` happens for these after **both** `OnTriggerEnter` have happend on the `0` object. I would rather make it event driven and let the `0` object change the color of the colliding `9` objects like:

```
 public class RedNumberNine : MonoBehaviour
 {
     // If possible already reference this via the Inspector
     [SerilaizeField] private Renderer rend;

     // Start is called before the first frame update
     private void Awake()
     {
         if(!rend) rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
     }

     public void SetRed()
     {
         rend.material.color = Color.red;
     }
 }
```

And then in the 0 script

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider col) 
{
    if (col.tag == "9")
    {
         // Add the GameObject collided with to the list.
         currentCollisions.Add (col.gameObject);
    }

    if (currentCollisions.Count == 2)
    {
        rend.material.color = Color.red;
        Debug.Log("collision");

        // color the two 9s
        foreach(var nine in currentCollisions)
        {
            nine.GetComponent<RedNumberNine>().SetRed();
        }
    }
}
```